# How to get primary outlook account using python

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I would like to get the primary outlook email address using python ,my code likes below:

```
import win32com.client as client
outlook=client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
accounts = outlook.Session.Accounts
print(accounts)
for i in accounts:
    print(i.SmtpAddress)
```

the error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7276/1677428506.py in <module>
      3 accounts = outlook.Session.Accounts
      4 print(accounts)
----> 5 for i in accounts:
      6     print(i.SmtpAddress)

TypeError: 'Accounts' object is not iterable
```

output expected: mail format (sth like abc@xyz.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my case already , the code below could work fine:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook_app = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
ons = outlook_app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
count1 = outlook_app.Session.Accounts.Count
print(count1)
for i in range(1,count1+1):

    if ons.Accounts.Item(i).DisplayName.lower().find("thakral") != -1:
        print(ons.Accounts.Item(i).DisplayName)
        print("TRUE")
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary Outlook account (note that OOM only exposes mail accounts, but not store or address book) will be the very first account in the `Namespace.Accounts` collection.